# Deserialization and validation of Boolean field

Tags: java, json, jackson

I figured out something about the Boolean getters and I would like to check if I have missed something or if it is a Jackson unmanaged use case.
I have 2 Java classes `Employee` and `PersonalData` and both of these classes have a Boolean attribute and their getter named as `public Boolean is...() {}`. `PersonalData` is also an attribute of `Employee`.

The "light" description of my classes is:

```java
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8106504890586067631L;

    @NotNull
    private Boolean activated;

    // StackOverflow comment : isActivated and not getActivated to match the Boolean getter naming rules
    public Boolean isActivated() {
        return activated;
    }

    public void setActivated(Boolean activated) {
        this.activated = activated;
    }

    // StackOverflow comment : @Valid to enhance child element validation
    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private PersonalData personalData;

    public PersonalData getPersonalData() {
        return personalData;
    }

    public void setPersonalData(PersonalData personalData) {
        this.personalData = personalData;
    }
}

public class PersonalData implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -61880360094142526L;

    /**
     * Gender - true if man, false if woman
     */
    @NotNull
    private Boolean man;    

    // isMan and not getMan to match the Boolean getter naming rules
    public Boolean isMan() {
        return man;
    }

    public void setMan(Boolean man) {
        this.man = man;
    }
}
```

My frontend is Angular so I send a Json of these classes to a controller method

```java
@PostMapping("/employees")
public ResponseEntity<Employee> createEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody Employee employee) throws URISyntaxException {
    // Stackoverflow comment : We don't really care of the content here
    return null;
}
```

I have tried 3 use cases :

1. a valid JSON -> it works fine as expected

   ```
   { 
       "activated": true,
       "personalData": {
           "man": true
       }
   }
   ```
2. an invalid json because `activated` is null. As expected, validation fails : BadRequest with message activated has to be NotNull

   ```
   {
       "activated": null, 
       "personalData": {
           "man": true
       }
   }
   ```
3. An invalid Json because `man` is null. **Unexpected result : Deserialization fails** : InternalServerError with message saying personalData.man could not be mapped

   ```
   {
       "activated": true, 
       "personalData": {
           "man": null
       }
   }
   ```

Now, if I rename my `isMan()` getter into `getMan()`, it fixes the issue and the 3rd use case then fails due to a validation issue as expected (idem 2nd use case). So, `isActivated` is Ok and `isMan` is not Ok.

So, did I miss something or did Jackson miss something (= to be deserialized, the getter attributes of a child element must be called `get...()` can't be `is...()`) ?

Comment: The `isXXX()` naming convention only applies to getters with a `boolean` return type, not a `Boolean` return type. When the return type is `Boolean`, the normal `getXXX` naming convention applies. However, I can't explain why that would lead to differences between the top-level and the nested property. If you want to enforce not-null, why not just use `boolean`?

Comment: What version of Jackson do you use? You should try the latest one. My code snippet below deserializes JSON with success with Jackson v.2.8.11.

Comment: I use 2.9.9 that currently is the latest available release.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I do agree with you about ```is...()``` for ```boolean``` and ```get...``` for ```Boolean```. My domain is generated from an object model (with a generator named jhipster) and the used data type is ```Boolean```. When meeting this issues, I had a look about best practices (to check before suggesting a change in the generator) and it seems some people say ```is...``` has also become the norm for ```Boolean```. So yes, I could change the data type but I wanted to avoid manual refactoring.

Comment: The [JavaBeans 1.01 specification](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html) only defines `isXXX` for `boolean` properties, so the norm for `Boolean` properties is `getXXX`.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, I suggest to use immutable object as Joshua Block wrote in his book. Therefore, try to add all args constructor and delete all setters.

PS: You can use lombok to consice the extra code adding annotation `@AllArgsConstructor, @Getter, @Setter` etc.

PSS: I can not reapet this issue. This is my code snippet:

```
class ExternalClass {
    private Boolean flag;
    private InternalClass internalClass;

    public Boolean isFlag() {
       return flag;
    }

    public void setFlag(Boolean flag) {
       this.flag = flag;
    }

    public InternalClass getInternalClass() {
       return internalClass;
    }

    public void setInternalClass(InternalClass internalClass) {
       this.internalClass = internalClass;
    }
}

class InternalClass {
   private Boolean flag;

   public Boolean isFlag() {
      return flag;
   }

   public void setFlag(Boolean flag) {
       this.flag = flag;
   }
}

public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    ExternalClass clazz1 = mapper.readValue("{\n" +
                                                   "  \"flag\": true,\n" +
                                                   "  \"internalClass\": {\n" +
                                                   "    \"flag\": false\n" +
                                                   "  }\n" +
                                                   "}", ExternalClass.class);

    ExternalClass clazz2 = mapper.readValue("{\n" +
                                                   "  \"flag\": null,\n" +
                                                   "  \"internalClass\": {\n" +
                                                   "    \"flag\": false\n" +
                                                   "  }\n" +
                                                   "}", ExternalClass.class);

    ExternalClass clazz3 = mapper.readValue("{\n" +
                                                   "  \"flag\": true,\n" +
                                                   "  \"internalClass\": {\n" +
                                                   "    \"flag\": null\n" +
                                                   "  }\n" +
                                                   "}", ExternalClass.class);
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and is more a comment about other aspects of the code.

Comment: You don't address the problem of the question, you say the OP should use immutable objects and use Lombok which are comments and not an answer. The fact you cannot reproduce the problem is also not an answer, because clearly the OP does have the problem. Again, that would warrant a comment to ask for a [mre].